# Quiero cambiar el estado de true a false

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que recoge datos de mi DB y crea una tabla para mostrar en mi `HTML`, a parte de eso, hice un botón con un escuchador o `listener` y un `input` para agregar la cantidad en otra tabla (que sirve para pagar).

Bueno el punto es que yo no quiero que se repitan los productos al momento de pagar, y por eso hice una validación con un `boolean`, como muestro en el siguiente código:

```
let isInCart = false;
btnAccept.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let valueOfInput = inputAddOrLess.value;
  if (valueOfInput.length === 0) {
    showMessage("You should first type", "red");
    return;
  }
  if (isInCart) {
    showMessage("Your product is in car", "red");
    return;
  }
  isInCart = true;
  tableForPay(valueOfInput, product, price, isInCart);
});

btnCancel.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  deletee(product);
});
```

Esto si funciona correctamente, pero en la función donde hago la otra tabla, tengo 2 botones mas en las `fila(row)`, para agregar o disminuir la cantidad de elementos:

```
btnLess.addEventListener("click", ({target:e}) => {
  if (count === 0) {
    deletee(tableRow);
    return false;
  }
  count--;
  parrafForQuantity.innerHTML = count;
  parrafForPrice.innerHTML = operation.less(number); 
});
```

Todo funciona bien, pero al momento de yo querer agregar de nuevo el mismo elemento (digamos que el cliente borra por casualidad el producto del carrito y lo quiere volver a ingresar) y salta la condición de la primera función (del booleano) que ya no deja volver a ingresar el mismo producto.

Por eso quiero que en la segunda función (o de otra forma) que el booleano vuelva a `false`, apuntando al mismo producto.

Answer (score 0):

Entonces, puedes setear nuevamente `isInCart` como `false` en la condicional `count === 0`.

```
if (count === 0) {
  deletee(tableRow);
  isInCart = false;
  return false;
}
```